# split rows of a column then make a column with the 2nd element R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, split, strsplit

This is hard for me, so please help me with this. I have a df that look like:

```
    col1      col2    col3
ccd_x29807 Gly_GCC_89 0.3
ccd_x29807 Gly_GCC_87 0.3
ccd_x29807 Gly_GCC_88 0.3
ccd_x20463 Lys_CTT_12 0.1
```

What I want to do is to save the values (after `x`) in a new column. So the output should look like:

```
    col1      col2   col3 col4
ccd_x29807 Gly_GCC_89 0.3 29807
ccd_x29807 Gly_GCC_87 0.3 29807
ccd_x29807 Gly_GCC_88 0.3 29807
ccd_x20463 Lys_CTT_12 0.1 20463
```

I tried this but it puts `29807` in all of the rows:

```
df1$col1 %>% 
  mutate(col4 = str_split(samples, "x")[[1]][2])'
```

Comment: @markus no it is variable. Those are counts from different records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use separate from the tidyr package.

```
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c("ccd_x29807", "ccd_x29807", "ccd_x29807", "ccd_x20463"),
  col2 = c("Gly_GCC_89", "Gly_GCC_87", "Gly_GCC_88", "Lys_CTT_12"),
  col3 = c(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1)
)

df %>%
  mutate(col_temp = col1) %>%
  separate("col_temp", into = c(NA, "col4"), sep = "x")
```

Output:

```
        col1       col2 col3  col4
1 ccd_x29807 Gly_GCC_89  0.3 29807
2 ccd_x29807 Gly_GCC_87  0.3 29807
3 ccd_x29807 Gly_GCC_88  0.3 29807
4 ccd_x20463 Lys_CTT_12  0.1 20463
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is via `stringr`s function `str_extract`:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("ccd_x29807","ccd_x29807","ccd_x29807","ccd_x20463"))
```

Solution:

```
df$col2 <- str_extract_all(df$col1, "(?<=x)\\d+")
```

This solution makes use of positive lookbehind: this part of the regex `(?<=x)` embodies the instruction "if in the string you see on the left an `x`", while this part of the regex `\\d+` matches a number repeated one or more times.

Another `base R`solution is via `gsub`and backreference `\\1`:

```
df$col2 <- gsub(".*x(\\d+)", "\\1", df$col1)
```

Alternatively, if you prefer `dplyr`:

```
df$col2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(col1 = str_extract_all(col1, "(?<=x)\\d+"))
```

Result:

```
df
        col1  col2
1 ccd_x29807 29807
2 ccd_x29807 29807
3 ccd_x29807 29807
4 ccd_x20463 20463
```